# In xv6 where does swtch.s return to?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, riscv, xv6

Pretty much the question was confused where does [Swtch.s](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/riscv/kernel/swtch.S) return to after being called in [sched()](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-riscv/blob/f5b93ef12f7159f74f80f94729ee4faabe42c360/kernel/proc.c#L481)

```
.globl swtch
swtch:
        sd ra, 0(a0)
        sd sp, 8(a0)
        sd s0, 16(a0)
        sd s1, 24(a0)
        sd s2, 32(a0)
        sd s3, 40(a0)
        sd s4, 48(a0)
        sd s5, 56(a0)
        sd s6, 64(a0)
        sd s7, 72(a0)
        sd s8, 80(a0)
        sd s9, 88(a0)
        sd s10, 96(a0)
        sd s11, 104(a0)

        ld ra, 0(a1)
        ld sp, 8(a1)
        ld s0, 16(a1)
        ld s1, 24(a1)
        ld s2, 32(a1)
        ld s3, 40(a1)
        ld s4, 48(a1)
        ld s5, 56(a1)
        ld s6, 64(a1)
        ld s7, 72(a1)
        ld s8, 80(a1)
        ld s9, 88(a1)
        ld s10, 96(a1)
        ld s11, 104(a1)
        
        ret
```

Also where is the lock of the process being released after we get into sched.
Would be really great if anyone could assist me on this

Comment: Returns to wherever the `$ra` of the new process points to which is where that process was switched away from.

Comment: So in that case when we call `swtch` in `sched` and give parameters as `swtch(p->context,mycpu->context)` we will save the context of the current process and then return to where scheduler thread was swtiched away from?

Comment: That `swtch` in `sched` will return to line 467 in the `scheduler` because the `mycpu->context` was saved with a `$ra` pointing there.

Comment: That actually makes sense thank you very much